# In Scala, is there a neat and simple way to compare one value with multiple values

Tags: scala, equality

Say I have a variable x, and I want to check if it's equal to  any one of multiple values a, b, c, d, e (I mean the == equality, not identity).

In an SQL query the same concept is handled with

```
WHERE x IN (a, b, c, d, e).
```

Is there something equivalent in Scala that's as straightforward as that?  I know it's otherwise possible to do it in one line with a complex expression such as building a HashSet and checking for existence in the set, but I'd prefer to use a simple construct if it's available.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would prefer `contains(a)` over `exists(_ == a)`:

```
scala> List(3, 4, 5) contains 4
res0: Boolean = true

scala> List(3, 4, 5) contains 6
res1: Boolean = false
```

Update: `contains` is defined in [`SeqLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqLike.html), so the above works with any sequence.

Update 2: Here is the definition of [`contains`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L537) in `SeqLike`:

```
def contains(elem: Any): Boolean = exists (_ == elem)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I voted you down, because I thought `contains` would just work with identity, not with equality. I voted you down and started to write a longer proof in my answer, but instead I proved myself wrong. Sorry. :)

Comment: @user And I voted your answer up because as you can see in my second update `contains(a)` is just sugar for `exists(_ == a)` so our answers are equivalent.

Comment: It might just be sugar, but I'm a sweet one, and since you edited your answer, I could correct my voting. (Scala is just syntactic sugar for Java, which is syntactic sugar for assembler ...).

Answer (score 24):

You could implement an `in` operator as follows:

```
scala> implicit def anyWithIn[A](a: A) = new {
     |   def in(as: A*) = as.exists(_ == a)
     | }
anyWithIn: [A](a: A)java.lang.Object{def in(as: A*): Boolean}

scala> 5 in (3, 4, 9, 11)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> 5 in (3, 4, 9, 11, 5)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: That's gorgeous.  Goes right into my own set of standard extensions that end up in all my projects, and arguably merits standard library inclusion

Comment: See my answer for how to do this the *other* way around: i.e. pimp a `A => Boolean` so you can write `5 ∈: Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: Neat! This should be built-in the next version of Scala.  But as it is, it would require explicitly importing or inheriting the implicit conversion everywhere it's needed, so for now I'm going with the List/contains technique.

Answer (score 12):

Given that a `Set[A]` is also a `A => Boolean`, you can just say:

```
Set(a, b, c, d, e) apply x
```

It's actually quite nice to define some pimpin' sugar for this:

```
class PredicateW[A](self : A => Boolean) {
  def ∈:(a : A) = self apply a
}
implicit def pred2wrapper[A](p : A => Boolean) = new PredicateW(p)
```

Then you can write the code like so:

```
x ∈: Set(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Comment: Another neat solution, thanks.  But I don't have the '∈' symbol on my US keyboard!

Answer (score 11):

By synthesizing all the other answers, I have come up with the *correct* answer:

```
implicit def anyWithIn[A](a: A) = new {
    def ∈(as: A*) = as.contains(a)
}
anyWithIn: [A](a: A)java.lang.Object{def ?(as: A*): Boolean}

5 ∈ (1,3,5)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Ta-da.

Comment: Hey, I will defend it as being demonstrably better than any other answer given so far (more legible than missingfaktor's solution, more pimplicious than Oxbow_lakes's, more comprehensible and Dan's...)

Answer (score 5):

exists:

```
 List (3, 4, 5).exists (_ == 4)
 // res20: Boolean = true
```

find and filter come close:

```
List (3, 4, 5).find (_ == 4)
// res16: Option[Int] = Some(4)
List (3, 4, 5).filter (_ == 4)
// res17: List[Int] = List(4)
```

My first answer was, as other answers, to use contain:

```
List (3, 4, 5).contains (4)
```

but then I thought, it would only work for boxed values like 4, not for classes, which distinguish identity and equality. To prove it, I wrote a small class, which proved **me** wrong: :)

```
class Ue (val i: Int) { 
  override def equals (other: Any) = other match {
    case o: Ue => i == o.i
    case _ => false }
}

val a = new Ue (4)
// a: Ue = Ue@1e040e5
val b = new Ue (4)
// b: Ue = Ue@1a4548b (no identity)
a == b
// res110: Boolean = true (surprise?) 
a.equals (b)
// res112: Boolean = true (expected)
a.eq (b)
// res113: Boolean = false (expected) 
List (a).contains (b)    
// res119: Boolean = true (surprise)
List (a).exists (_ == b) 
// res120: Boolean = true (expected) 
List (a).exists (_ .eq (b)) 
// res121: Boolean = false (expected)
```

I see, I have to use equals/eq/== more often, to get the distinctions into my brain.

```
List (3, 4, 5).contains (4)
```

is imho the answer which is most easy.

Answer (score 4):

`Set(a, b, c, d, e)(x)` works as well. I'll leave the reasons for it as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Ue (val i: Int) { 
  override def equals (other: Any) = other match {
    case o: Ue => i == o.i
    case _ => false }
}

val a = new Ue (4)
// a: Ue = Ue@1e040e5
val b = new Ue (4)
// b: Ue = Ue@1a4548b (no identity)
a == b
// res110: Boolean = true (surprise?) 
a.equals (b)
// res112: Boolean = true (expected)
a.eq (b)
// res113: Boolean = false (expected) 
List (a).contains (b)    
// res119: Boolean = true (surprise)
List (a).exists (_ == b) 
// res120: Boolean = true (expected) 
List (a).exists (_ .eq (b)) 
// res121: Boolean = false (expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution which also works with Scala 3:

```
implicit class PowerAny[A](a: A) {
  /**
   * 2 in (1,2,3,"foo") -> true
   *
   * 4 in (1,2,3,"foo") -> false
   */
  def in(seq: A*): Boolean = seq.contains(a)
}
```

(My request to update one of the other solutions was rejected.)