# Scala "belongsTo" function

Tags: scala

I am often in the situation of doing this type of filtering:

```
allPeople
  .filter(person => englishPeopleIds contains person.id)
```

and it would make my life easier and my code more readable if there was some sort of "belongsTo" function to do the following:

```
allPeople
  .filter(_.id belongsTo englishPeopleIds)
```

belongsTo function would have this kind of behaviour (but would be a method of the element):

```
def belongsTo[T](element: T, list: List[T]): Boolean = list contains element
```

Do you know if such function is already implemented in Scala?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185989/scala-equivalent-of-pythons-in-operator-for-sets

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps define a [right-associative operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15384749/5205022) on a sequential collections like so

```
implicit class ElementOf[A](l: Seq[A]) {
  def ∈: (a: A): Boolean = l contains a
}
```

using mathematical symbol *element of* ∈ which falls under Scala [operator characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657692/5205022), and then call-site becomes

```
allPeople filter (_.id ∈: englishPeopleIds)
```

---

To make it work also for `Set` and `Map` as well try defining in terms of `Iterable#exists` like so

```
implicit class ElementOf[A](cc: Iterable[A]) {
  def ∈: (a: A): Boolean = cc exists (_ == a)
}
```

Comment: Please don't! Haha - Anyways, same suggestions as the other comment.

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more user-friendly. You also need 
`implicit class Intersection[A](val coll: Iterable[A]) {
    def ∩(other: Iterable[A]): Unit = {
      coll.filter(_ ∈ other)
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could use an implicit class to do the same:

```
implicit class BelongsTo[T](private val t: T) extends AnyVal {
  def belongsTo(s: Seq[T]): Boolean = s.contains(t)
  def belongsTo(s: Set[T]): Boolean = s(t)
}
```

In Dotty, you can do this:

```
extension [T](t: T):
  def belongsTo(s: Seq[T]): Boolean = s.contains(t)
  def belongsTo(s: Set[T]): Boolean = s(t)
```

Honestly, though, it doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Make the implicit class also an **AnyVal** to avoid the cost of instantiation. Also, it may be worth to make it work for any collection, not juts lists.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I tried to apply your suggestion, but it seems `contains` isn't present in Iterable and is implemented differently in Set, Seq, and Map?

Comment: Really? Dude, abstracting over collections is really weird.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, it inspired someone to make this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-hist